# Assign tuple value to a global var

Tags: scala

I know I should not use var since it's not pure anyway, it's possible in Scala do something like this?

```
  var a: Int = 0
  var b: Int = 4

  (a, b) = (4, 8)
```

So far I'm receiving a compilation error

```
Error:(73, 10) ';' expected but '=' found.
  (a, b) = (4, 8)
```

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is "no".

A simple solution is to store `a` and `b` as a tuple and unpack them as needed:

```
var ab = (0, 4)

ab = (4, 8)

val (a, b) = ab
// Use a and b
```

---

The problem is that Scala does not support multiple assignment, which is what is required here. It can only de-structure a tuple as part of a declaration or a `match` statement.